# Tool to install fonts on demand

Tags: macos, software, font

I have too much fonts installed on my Mac, so photoshop (or indesign) can take a long time on operations that involve them (program startup, selecting them on the character palette etc)

I'm looking for a simple software, with an interface similar to Font Book (better if more compact), that allow me to view all the fonts inserted on it (but not in the system), and install temporarily on the system a desired font as I need it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few really good font managers out there that offer you this capability.

[Suitcase Fusion](http://www.extensis.com/suitcase-fusion-4/?gclid=CI_gjOC72rECFVBapgodHykACQ)'s been around for a long time and is really popular, personally I find it a bit bloated though.

[Fontcase](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/fontcase/) is probably the most similar interface to fontbook and is also one of the most popular. It used to be my favourite, but i've found it buggy in ML.

[Font Explorer X](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/) is again popular and has been around a while.

[Type DNA](http://www.typedna.com/) is an interesting new contender, it was one of the first apps to get it's plugins working with CS6. They're also offering 6 month free trials to students.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [FontExplorer X](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/pro/). It can auto-activate your fonts, so that they are available if you need them and disable them if you don't. Also you can activate and deactivate fonts manually.

Comment: But is there a way to see one complete directory of my fonts with a little example, a miniature, behind everyone of them? As the look I see when I open the characters palette in photoshop, illustrator, indesign, word, etc... ? (this to avoid to slide fonts one by one everytime).... thanks